# Tomcat Redirect Issue - Extra "/" after hostname - Help Please

Tags: tomcat

All,

We are running into a peculiar issue.

We have Tomcat 6.0.24 front-ended by Apache2.2.3.  We have a VirtualHost serving port 80 and a ServerAlias. Apache simply hands off "/" to Tomcat's load-balancer.

---------httpd.conf snippet:--------

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu
    ServerAlias wwwprod www www.lsa.umich.edu
    Redirect         / balancer://dsmdelivery/
    ProxyPass        / balancer://dsmdelivery/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://dsmdelivery/
    TraceEnable Off
</VirtualHost>
```

------------End of httpd.conf snippet----

Tomcat is tacking on an extra "/" as it creates a 302 response for one of the Server Aliases, and not the other as in the curl output below, when the URI does not have a trailing "/".

So you'll notice that:

http://www.lsa.umich.edu/polisci  <== comes back with a "//" in Location Header of the the 302 redirect response message

http://wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu/polisci  <==  does not have a "//" in the Location header of the 302

-------------- Curl output for both virtual hosts:-------------

```
$ curl -v  http://wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu/polisci
* About to connect() to wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 141.211.177.191... connected
* Connected to wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu (141.211.177.191) port 80 (#0)
GET /polisci HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
Host: wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu
Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Location: http://wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu/polisci/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2011 20:28:29 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host wwwprod.lsa.umich.edu left intact
* Closing connection #0
$
$
$ curl -v  http://www.lsa.umich.edu/polisci
* About to connect() to www.lsa.umich.edu port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 141.211.177.203... connected
* Connected to www.lsa.umich.edu (141.211.177.203) port 80 (#0)
GET /polisci HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
Host: www.lsa.umich.edu
Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily < Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2011 20:28:47 GMT
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Location: http://www.lsa.umich.edu//polisci/
< Content-Length: 0
< X-Cnection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: BIGipServerlsa-cmsproddlv_pool=3232879501.20480.0000; path=/
<
* Connection #0 to host www.lsa.umich.edu left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

---

Notice the "//" in the second output above.  This is causing the links to break.

(Both virtual hosts have a virtual server defined on the F5.  The "www.lsa.umich.edu" virtual server has iRules attached to it.  These haven't changed recently.)

Appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I traced the problem to a missing "ProxyPreserveHost On" directive on the LSA and the II VirtualHosts.  I added the missing directive, and things are working fine.

Apache documentation says:

> When enabled, this option will pass the Host: line from the incoming
>   request to the proxied host, instead of the hostname specified in the
>   proxypass line.
>
> This option should normally be turned Off. It is mostly useful in
>   special configurations like proxied mass name-based virtual hosting,
>   where the original Host header needs to be evaluated by the backend
>   server.

In our case, we are doing mass name-based virtual hosting and were missing this directive.

Comment: @JoseK from what I read this is an answer. The user was able to solve the problem themselves and has posted their answer for everyone else's use, this is perfectly acceptable.